# AWS Lambda is returning empty json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Im trying to return json strings in AWS lambda. This code worked on my local machine but, in AWS lambda empty json strings are returned.
Relevant parts of my code is given below

```
import json
import time as time
import pandas as pd                        
from pytrends.request import TrendReq #to connect to google trends and request trends
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date


def lambda_handler(event, context):
   #irrelevant parts of code here
   #......
    DfmergedTopJson = DfmergedTop.to_json(orient="records") #DfmergedTop is dataframe
    DfmergedRiseJson = DfmergedRise.to_json(orient="records") #DfmergedRiseJson is a df 
    dfjson = df.to_json(orient="records")
    return DfmergedTopJson, DfmergedRiseJson
```

Output is

```
Test Event Name
EventGoogle
Response
[
  "[]",
  "[]"
]
```

Actually my output is a long json string which i successfully printed in my local machine.
Please suggest me possible solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

1. did your Lambda function really generate values you expected? use the `print` function to log runtime variables, i.e.:
   `DfmergedTopJson` and `DfmergedRiseJson`, to CloudWatch Log, then evaluate the logs.
2. you may also want to log the `event` object
   to see what's sent to your Lambda function, the content might not be
   what you expected.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-logging.html